# Dictionary merging in Hy

Tags: hy

If I have two dictionaries, and want to merge them with preference to the latter regarding conflicting keys, I would do in Python:

```py
In [1]: x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

In [2]: y = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}

In [3]: {**x, **y}
Out[3]: {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}
```

How can I write this expression in Hy's syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary-unpacking operator is `unpack-mapping`, or `#**` for short.

```
=> (setv x {"a" 1  "b" 2})
=> (setv y {"b" 3  "c" 4})
=> {#** x  #** y}
{"a" 1  "b" 3  "c" 4}
```